First API call is slow
I made on a shared OVH hosting an API with Symfony 7 for the backend.
The frontend is under Angular 18.2
Everything works fine except for the first API call which is allways slowlier than the other.

I did the connector with Curl then i change for Guzzle, it has improved the response time but it is allways too slow.
Initialy i did the Front with AngularJS 1.82, and so then i change to Angular 18.2
It does not improved performance but i can use modern tools like RXJS to improve API Calls.
Do you have any ideas for improving first call response time ?
Here is my adaptator code for the token creation and a simple GET
Token
    public function generateCreatioToken() {
    $client = new Client();

    $options = [
        'form_params' => [
          'client_id' => $this->clientId,
          'client_secret' => $this->clientSecret,
          'grant_type' => 'client_credentials'
        ]];
    $request = new Request( 'POST', $this->oauthurl .'/connect/token', 
                            ['headers' => ['User-Agent' => null]]);
    $res = $client->sendAsync($request, $options)->wait();

    return json_decode($res->getBody());
}

Get
    /*
 * READ
 * Requête en GET sur CRM
 * $apiQuery: array dont le contenu des éléments est encodé en URL
 */
public function WSGETBPM($collection, $apiQuery, $token, $nbresult = 10000) {

    $client = new Client();
    $headers = [
      'Accept' => 'application/json; odata=verbose',
      'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token,
      'User-Agent' => null
    ];
    
    $targetUrl = $this->urlapi . '/0/ServiceModel/EntityDataService.svc/' . $collection;
    if (count($apiQuery) > 0) {
        $targetUrl .= '?' . implode('&', array_map(function ($item) {
            return $item[0] . '=' . $item[1];
        }, array_map(null, array_keys($apiQuery), $apiQuery)));
    }
    $request = new Request('GET', $targetUrl, $headers);
    $res = $client->sendAsync($request)->wait();
    return $res->getBody();
}

With Angular my service code:
  getOrderNumberById(orderId: string): Observable<OrderValidation> {
const options = { params: new HttpParams().set('orderId', orderId) };
return this.http.post<OrderValidation>(this.url + 'Creatio/getOrderNumberById', options).pipe(
  retry(3),
  catchError(this.handleError)
)

}
Using an interceptor:
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
const authToken = this.authService.getAuthToken();

const authReq = request.clone({
  setHeaders: {
    'Authorization': `${authToken}`,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
  }
})


This is very likely an issue with your backend, not the frontend. It's the response (backend) that takes that long, not the initiator (frontend). Is your API cold starting when the first request hits thus taking longer maybe?

i think too it is coming from the backend and Yes the API is cold starting.

@LenwëGalathil PHP preloading and Symfony is a performance gain. But you need to have access to php.ini and not share it with other applications.

i can't edit the php.ini, i m on an shared host

@LenwëGalathil Then try to cache data in your application that can be cached. I see in your code samples that you are making an API call there. You may be able to achieve a performance gain with this.

So i added code for guzzle cache and a task planned which make an API call at least one time per hour. it lloks good ! tku Bademeister !

Also, don't forget to warm up the cache. bin/console cache:warmup.

On my API Adapter i added Guzzle Cache:
    $stack = HandlerStack::create();
    $stack->push(new CacheMiddleware(), 'cache');
    // Initialize the client with the handler option
    $client = new Client(['handler' => $stack]);

In the .htaccess:
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Connection keep-alive
</ifModule>

And i added a planned task which make at least an API call per hour.
It looks good.
